# How to set the same value on multiple keys

Tags: javascript

How is it possible to set the same value on multiple keys? For example I have the following object:

```
const obj = {
   a: 5,
   b: 5,
   c: 5,
   d: 6
}
```

Is there any easy way for example lets say I have array of [a, b, c] (keys) and to spread them in object and set them as keys with same value. Point is to look more classy for example:

```
const keys =[a, b, c]
const obj = {
  [...keys]: 5
}
```

I know this would throw error but looking for some shorthand to achieve this

Comment: What do you mean? What is your expected output here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take the array of keys and map each to an entry of the key and the `5` value:

```js
const keys = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const obj = {
  ...Object.fromEntries(
    keys.map(key => [key, 5])
  ),
  d: 6
};

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like this works:

```
const obj = {};
const value = 5;
['a', 'b', 'c'].forEach(key => obj[key] = value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build a zip function which takes an array of keys and a array of values and returns an object where each key/value pair is taken from their respective index:

```js
const zip =
  (ks, vs) =>
    ks.reduce((o, k, i) =>
      (o[k] = vs[i], o), {});

zip(['a', 'b', 'c'], [5, 5, 5]);
//=> {a: 5, b: 5, c: 5}
```

If you need to generate an array of `5`:

```
Array(3).fill(5);
//=> [5, 5, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could take a spreading of `Object.assign` with a spreaded array of objects.

```js
const
    keys = ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    obj = { ...Object.assign(...keys.map(k => ({ [k]: 5 }))), d: 6 };
    
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   function(item)
   {
      return  Object.keys(item).reduce((a, b) => ({ ...a, [b]:5 }),{});
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: I think the question is asking for a way to select which keys to set to the same value. This answer sets *everything* to the same value. Other issues: **a.** Not sure why you decided to wrap this in a function. The point of defining a function is to re-use it. This function is anonymous (not reusable in the context your have provided) and doesn't allow input of the value to set, which would be much more useful, I think. **b.** This is copying objects several times when you use the spread in the predicate. This makes this solution O(n^2), when it can easily be done in O(n) and in-place.